# List to csv delimited by comma and new line python

Tags: python

I have a list which I want to write to a CSV file and i want it to be delimited by comma followed by a newline.
I have tried writerows but this splits all the characters.
I have tried writerow but this gives me all in one row delimited by comma but no newline for each entry.

**My attempt**

```
import  csv

mylist = ['AFCIEUR ID', 'CSCIB25 LX' , 'GAMCOIE ID']

writer = open("my_EQ_IDs.csv", 'w+')
writer_out = csv.writer(writer,delimiter='\n')
fields = ['SYMBOL']
writer_out.writerow(fields)
writer_out.writerows(mylist)
```

This gives me

```
SYMBOL

A
F
C
I
E
U
R
 
I
D

C
S
C
I
B
2
5
 
L
X

G
A
M
C
O
I
E
 
I
D
```

If I use `writerow` instead of `writerows` i get the below

```
SYMBOL

AFCIEUR ID
CSCIB25 LX
GAMCOIE ID
```

This is close to what i want but it's not separated by comma as I need. I have tried adding delimiter as `delimiter=',\n'` but this gives me an error `TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string`

**I need (Expected Output)**

```
SYMBOL

AFCIEUR ID,
CSCIB25 LX,
GAMCOIE ID
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you use the comma in the delimiter? delimiter=',\n'

Comment: I tried that and you get error of ```TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual result is caused by a string being an iterable. You pass a list of string to `writerows` which expects an iterable of iterables. So each character of the values is taken as a field followed by the field delimiter which you have set to the new line.

But the expected file is not a valid csv file. You use the sequence `',\n'` (2 characters) as a delimiter when the Python csv module only defines the delimiter to be a single character. So you cannot expect the csv module to produce the expected result...

That means that you should write you file *by hand*. It is easy using `join`:

```
with open("my_EQ_IDs.csv", 'w+') as writer:
    print('SYMBOL', file=writer)
    print(',\n'.join(mylist), file=writer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Serge Ballesta! You provided the solution as well as teaching about ```join``` which i will now look into.

Answer (score 0):

try including the comma in the delimiter: `delimiter=',\n'`

Comment: I tried that and you get error of ```TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string```

Answer (score 0):

Try using lineterminator='\n' and delimiter=',' - should work.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected it prints
```SYMBOL
AFCIEUR ID,CSCIB25 LX,GAMCOIE ID```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
mylist = ['AFCIEUR ID', 'CSCIB25 LX' , 'GAMCOIE ID']
with open('my_output_file.csv','w') as f:
    for item in mylist:
        f.write(f'{item},\n')
```

Comment: You could use f.write(",\n".join(myList)) to avoid the trailing comma

Comment: Thank you alec and Frederik.. The solution did work and I am grateful for that. However, there was a more efficient answer which I accepted . Thanks for your help!!